# Postfix transport: deliver different domains via different relayhosts

Tags: email, postfix-mta

Postfix version 2.11.0

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have mail destined for a particular domain to be relayed through SendGrid but all other outgoing mail to be sent from my local server directly.  I have this configuration in `/etc/postfix/transport`:

```
example.com smtp:[smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
.example.com smtp:[smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
*   :
```

My understanding from all the searches I've done and reading the Postfix docs is that this should work but if I send to any other domain, for example `gmail.com` it's still getting relayed through SendGrid.

An example from `/var/log/mail.log`:

```
Oct 26 16:15:46 myhost postfix/smtp[25783]: A75F0C04F9: to=<PRIVACY_MASKED@gmail.com>, relay=smtp.sendgrid.net[108.168.190.108]:587, delay=11, delays=11/0.02/0.22/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok: queued as iTwf5zmCQQSgz_I6sVpSSA)
```

Is there some other configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now I see the error of my ways.  In sasl_passwd I had this:

```
smtp.sendgrid.net USERNAME:PASSWD
```

But in transport I had this:

```
example.com smtp:[smtp.sendgrid.com]:587
```

The difference is `.net` versus `.com`.

Changed it to .net and works!